# Unix sockets doesn't work with PHP on Apache

Tags: php, apache, sockets, unix-socket

I wrote a following short script in PHP:

```
<?
$s = socket_create(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
socket_connect($s,"/tmp/tmpsock");
socket_write($s,"test");
socket_close($s);
>
```

I user this code to connect to a simple server that prints everything it receives onto terminal output.

The script works fine when I opened it from terminal using `php index.php`, however I want it to be a part of a webapp, and I try to run it on apache2 server opening the index.php page in web browser (on server of course). The script doesn't work then - the `socket_connect` function returns nothing, the error description is "Success()" and the message doesn't appear on server.
I use Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0

Comment: Does the user who the PHP script is executing as under Apache (maybe apache, httpd, noboby, someone else) have permission to write to /tmp/tmpsock ?

Comment: Thanks! That was the answer, thank you! It didn't.